# Multiple items have the same description

Tags: android, publish, wear-os, android-number-picker, prelaunch

I am working on Android Wear OS App development with Android Studio
I got report by Google like this.

[image]

As you can see I got issue with the NumberPicker.

```
<NumberPicker
   android:id="@+id/numberPickerSecond"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
   android:formatter="@{model::formatNumber}"
   android:value="@={model.secondPickerValue}"
   app:maxValue="@{60}"
   app:minValue="@{0}" />
```

Here is Layout of my Timer.
How to fix for Report issue?

I tried to add `android:importantForAccessibility="no"` on `NumberPicker`.
But I can make sure it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
app:maxValue="@{59}"
```

The two values `00` and `60` mean the same...

Answer (score 0):

@Cloverleaf has a good point, and you should definitely remove the "60" option from both pickers.

However, I believe the issue reported is actually caused by the lack of a content description for your pickers. You have two number pickers on the same screen and no explicit content description. This means that they will be announced in the exact same way by the screen reader, which is confusing to say the least.

The solution would be to add a content description to each of the pickers:

```
android:contentDescription="@string/number_picker_minutes_content_description"
```

and

```
android:contentDescription="@string/number_picker_seconds_content_description"
```

To test it, turn on the screen reader in Settings -> Accessibility -> TalkBack

More details about accessibility can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/apps#describe-ui-element) in the official documentation.